# Запятая перед "совместно с"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В тексте дана программа фестиваля. Один из пунктов программы:

чч:мм–чч:мм **Выставка «Название», совместно с поэтическим клубом «Название»**

Нужна ли запятая перед "совместно с"?

Answer (score 1):

Вторая часть носит пояснительный характер, поэтому должна быть выделена. Лучше использовать скобки, запятая — хуже, без запятой — совсем плохо (получится странный гибрид "выставка с клубом").

Answer (score 0):

Придадим удобный вид строчке (отбросим дату открытия или время работы): «Выставка "X" совместно с поэтическим клубом "Y"».

Очевидно, что здесь не хватает сказуемого (организована, создана, проводится и т. д.), а также не называется другая сторона — организатор выставки, хотя возможно, что эти сведения содержатся в другом месте условного баннера.

Три варианта. Фразу разбить на две строки без знака препинания. Вторичную информацию забрать в скобки. Фразу дополнить: «**Выставка** "**X**" **подготовлена совместно с поэтическим клубом** "**Y**"».

Если название выставки ("**X**") представить как титульный элемент, то вслед за ним, ниже, фраза будет выглядеть так: «**Выставка подготовлена совместно с поэтическим клубом** "**Y**"».